# How to define args in nestjs-graphql with MongoDB type arguments?

Tags: nestjs, typegraphql

I have the following query in my resolvers:

```js
    import { Args, Query } from '@nestjs/graphql';
    import { Collection, FilterQuery, FindOneOptions } from 'mongodb';

    ...

    @Query(returns => [Recipe])
    async recipes(
        @Args() query:   FilterQuery<Collection>,
        @Args() options: FindOneOptions
    ):  Promise<Recipe[]> {
        return this.recipeService.findAll();
    }
```

I am trying to allow for the arguments of `query` and `options` to be used whenever querying the recipes.

The two issues I run into are as follows:

- When I run as is, it tells me:

  > Error: You need to provide explicit type for RecipeResolver#recipes parameter #1!
- Otherwise, if I try to pass the types as arguments into the `@Args` declarative, like so `@Args({type: () => FilterQuery}) query: FilterQuery<Collection>` I get:

  > 'FilterQuery' only refers to a type, but it is being used as a value here.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make an class that looks like the `FilterQuery` and `FindOneOptions` that you are trying to use, but have the `type-graphql` type decorators on their properties so that the GraphQL server can know how to expect the formatting of `FilterQuery` and `FindOneOptions` to look.